# Creating a multi array from query

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

Im working with Charts4Php and laravel 5.1 but i need to return a multi array result from a query to the DB

Array Example

```
array(
  array(
   array('Charts',6),
   array('Apple',8),
   array('Hone',14),
   array('Gas',20)));
```

Array Return

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:4 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "Charts"
      1 => 6
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "Apple"
      1 => 8
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => "Hone"
      1 => 14
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      0 => "Gas"
      1 => 20
    ]
  ]
]
```

Array Returned from Query

```
    array:1 [▼
    0 => {#193 ▼
    +"Apple": 55
    +"Car": 22
    +"House": 66
    +"Gas": 5
  }
]
```

Controller

```
$p = new \chartphp();
$DB = DB::Table('users')->select('Apple','Car','House','Gas')->where('id', '=', '2')->get();
 $p->data = $DB;
 $p->chart_type = "pie";
$p->title = "";
  $out = $p->render('c2');
    return('pages.test')->with('out',$out);
```

View only contains one line

```
{!!$out!!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Mwaa Joseph i found out i had to literate though it two times instead of once thank you for your help

```
foreach($DB as $ind => $val) {
                foreach($val as $x => $y){
                    $fields[] =  [$x, $y];
                }

}
```

returned array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Apple"
      1 => 55
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Car"
      1 => 22
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "House"
      1 => 66
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Gas"
      1 => 5
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider looping through the query results to transform it to the required multi-dimensional structure.

Example

```
$fields = [];
foreach($DB as $ind => $val) {
  $fields[] =  [$ind, $val]
}
$data = [ $fields ]; //Finally wrap them inside an array
```

Comment: I had to illiterate though it again